# Celery no ejecuta algunas tareas

Tags: python, django, celery, redis

En una aplicación Django intento enviar mails asíncronamente usando Celery, los objetos tasks son creados, pero no llegan a Celery.

Acá muestro los id de los tasks creados:

```
0: d51a86c2-219d-44a5-a004-2ff00f13f229

1: 47979e10-643c-4ced-808a-bdefb2a1779f

2: e52b0a58-3742-4547-9f37-0fe5b065a8ae
```

Pero en mi Celery shell.

```
python manage.py celery worker -l info -Ofair --settings=project.settings.staging
```

Sólo se ejecutan algunas tareas:

```
[2016-12-19 17:15:17,582: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: apps.enrollment.tasks.send_email_professor[d51a86c2-219d-44a5-a004-2ff00f13f229]
[2016-12-19 17:15:17,586: WARNING/Worker-5] 0
[2016-12-19 17:15:17,610: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: apps.enrollment.tasks.send_email_purchase[e52b0a58-3742-4547-9f37-0fe5b065a8ae]
[2016-12-19 17:15:17,616: WARNING/Worker-6] 2
[2016-12-19 17:15:17,992: WARNING/Worker-6] email sent
[2016-12-19 17:15:18,152: WARNING/Worker-5] email sent
```

A veces sólo la 1, a veces 0 y 2, y a veces 1 y 2. Los print los hago al inicio de cada task.

Mi configuración de Celery y Redis es:

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
BROKER_TRANSPORT = 'redis'
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 800000,}
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERYD_POOL_RESTARTS = True
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 8
CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True
CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
REDIS_NOTIFICATION_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_NOTIFICATION_PORT = 6379
REDIS_NOTIFICATION_DB = 5
```

Un ejemplo de una de los tasks:

```
@app.task
def send_email_purchase_notification_admin(enrollment):
     print '2'
     course = enrollment.course
     user = enrollment.user
     professor = course.professor
     from_email = "Project <hola@project.com>"
     subject = "Congrats!"

     msg = EmailMessage(
        subject=subject, from_email=from_email, to=["user@project.com"]
     )
     msg.template_name = "purchase-notification-admin"
     msg.merge_vars = {
        "user@project.com": {
            'FNAME': ' '.join(
                [user.first_name, user.last_name]
            ) if user.first_name.strip() else user.username,
            'COURSE': course.title.title(),
            'PROFESSOR': ' '.join([professor.first_name,   professor.last_name]),
            'PRICE': str(course.price),
        },
    }
    msg.tags = ["payment"]
    send_mail(msg)
```

Comment: Puedes añadir el codigo de como creas las task para saber como estas haciendo

Comment: Hola, ya agregué un ejemplo de un tasks, la cosa es que creo que no importa mucho eso, ya que se puede ver que se crean los objetos de los tasks (muestro los id), pero en el shell del Celery no llegan siempre. Creo que va más por la configuración de Celery.

Answer (score 0):

Si no puede hacer que los scripts de inicio funcionen, debería intentar ejecutarlos en modo detallado :

```
sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

o puedes forzar esto con este comando:

```
sudo c_fakefork=1 sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```